# UIScrollView frame not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, view, scrollview

I have a UIScrollView which animates UIImageViews by setting contentOffSet and upon tap gesture it expands to self.view.frame. After upgrading to 7.1 I cannot set the frame any more. It remains the same buts its contentView resizes as expected. What am I missing?

```
if (!isFullScreen) {




[UIView animateWithDuration:.7 animations:^{

    [ima setAlpha:1];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_scrollView];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [_scrollView setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [_scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    for (UIImageView *im in _scrollView.subviews) {
        [im setFrame:CGRectMake(im.frame.origin.x+10, im.frame.origin.y, _scrollView.frame.size.width-20, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [im setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [im setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];


    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. To anyone having the same issue the problem was that the viewController was set to Autolayout option which raises another issue. Why does the Autolayout prevails over the actual dynamic changes of any view?